# Convert a list of strings to a list of numbers Python

Tags: python, regex, list

I am using regular expressions in Python 3 to obtain a list of value:

```
lst = ['1.1' , '2.2' , '3.3']
```

Instead, I want a list of numbers as below:

```
lst = [1.1 , 2.2 , 3.3]
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, since it' already used by a built-in function.

Comment: Since you're using Python 3, you could try: `lst = list(map(float, lst))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try python's `map` function.  It takes a function and an iterable and applies the function to each item in the iterable.

```
lst = list(map(float, lst))
```

The call to `list` is required in python 3, because the built-in map function returns a special map object as opposed to a list. 
I would also recommend not using `list` as a variable name, as `list` is a built-in function in python.

Comment: The OP is using Python 3.x, where `map` no longer returns a list.  You need to do: `lst = list(map(float, lst))`.

Comment: Good catch -- I'll add in the cast to list.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "cast". It's just a creation of a list from an iterable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
lst = ['1.1' , '2.2' , '3.3']
lst = [float(x) for x in lst]
```

I'm using `lst` here because `list` is already taken by the builtin `list`.